# dropdowlist [object object]

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I discover with dropdownlist.

Indeed I load data by a query  to mysql Database.

But in mysql one record has empty field.

And in this case flex display [object object] instead of ' '.

```
[Bindable] private var DP_CLASSES:ArrayCollection;

<s:DropDownList id="dpClassTT" width="77" 
    dataProvider="{DP_CLASSES}"labelField="Nom"
    />
```

// DataProvider sample

```
 <TypesTT>
   <TypeTT>
     <Nom> </Nom>
   </TypeTT>
   <TypeTT>
     <Nom>AppA</Nom>
   <TypeTT>
<TypesTT>
```

The line [Objet object] appear on dropdownlist even if name is empy (like record one).

Do you know how to solve that?

Thanks

Comment: Show some code, perhaps?

Comment: Create own DataProvider by removing blank entries or by finding blank entries in arraycollection by using something like below if(arrayCollection.contains(blankEntry)) than remove that particular item from ArrayCollection.

Comment: Ok, it's a solution, but how to add a blank entry on a dropdownlist? Indeed sometimes user make a mistake and wants to clear selected item, how it's possible?

Comment: At user level if user try to add blank entry check it at client side by using StringUtils.trim(UserEnteredValue) if it is blank show error dialog and don't allow user to enter blank value(restrict user from adding blank value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can say from the limited information you have posted here is that you need to set the `labelField` of the dropdownlist.

You can do this in mxml like

```
<s:DropDownList dataProvider="{myQuery}" labelField="colName" />
```

or, you set a labelFunction like:

```
<s:Script>
    private function toLabel(item:Object):String {
        return item["colName"].toString();
    }
</s:Script>
<s:DropDownList dataProvider="{myQuery}" labelFunction="toLabel" />
```

**EDIT** after you've updated your question, I believe it is better to use the labelFunction.

Your labelFunction would be something like this:

```
function toLabel(item:Object):String {
    var str:String=item["Nom"] as String;
    if(str==null || str==undefined) {
        str="";
    }
    return str;
}
```

We need to do this because the empty tag `Nom` is taken as an XMLList object in AS3, which is why it is necessary to cast it.

Comment: A problem appear when I post, so a complete my question. Thanksq